# Не ставится php7 на ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

Подскажите пожалуйста, со вчера не могу поставить php7 на ubuntu 14.04, выполняю следующие команды:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку и по итогу могу поставить php и его пакеты только php5

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

После установки новой (старой) версии php, нужно выполнить переключение текущего интерпретатора с одной версии на другую
sudo a2dismod php5.0 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Ни одной версии еще не установлено, а суть в том, что не могу установить php7, после добавления репозитория есть возможность установить только php5. А при установке php7.0 или php5.6 пишет - что нет таких пакетов.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/php#%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_php

Comment: Спасибо за ссыль, но чем это отличается от того, как я делал(выше описывал) =) Сделал: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php, потом sudo apt-get update.... Запустил - sudo apt-get install php5.6. и получил - E: Unable to locate package php5.6  E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.6'

Comment: Возможно я что-то делаю не так, хотя я же говорю, что раньше эти шаги отрабатывали отлично =(

Answer (score 0):

Наверное я нашел ответ:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) reached End of Life on April 25 2019 (ESM available)
```

```
Only Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.
```

Последнее взято отсюда:
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте установить нужную версию не через менеджер пакетов, а из исходников https://github.com/php/php-src.

https://php.net/manual/ru/install.unix.php тут есть более подробная инструкция.

Использовал такой подход, когда нужно было установить php7.3 на openSUSE, а в официальных репозиториях не было этой версии.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, в таком варианте модули отдельно нужно доставлять? Например, xml, zip, ssh2, soap

Comment: Чтобы установить некоторые модули нужно будет перекомпилировать заново
./configure 
...
  --with-curl 
...

А вот, например, по поводу soap https://php.net/manual/fr/soap.installation.php

Comment: Или же можно попробовать ставить отдельно, убедившись в соответствии версий, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/install.pecl.phpize.php